# Databricks Timestamp format - How to find exact format?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

When I tried to display the date column from pyspark dataframe through show() and display(dataframe) ,those format of the data columns are different . Now how do we arrive which date format is being there in dataframe ?

Display : 2018-02-15T06:47:19.000+0000

show : 2018-02-15 06:47:19

[image]

Comment: You can use `datetime.datetime.strftime` and  `datetime.datetime.strptime` to format and parse timestamp strings. The stored string looks to be in UTC timezone.

Comment: `show` should give the more accurate representation.

Comment: @progmatico `datetime` can only be used for Python objects, not dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp in dataframe isn't stored as a string - it's stored using internal representation ([Long in case of `timestamp`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/TimestampType.scala#L40)) that is then converted into text by `show` or `display`.