# How to resolve Spark sql timestamp without T symbol and + symbol

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I use the below functions in pyspark, it creates a timestamp with T and + in it.

version --> Spark 3.3

How do I create a timestamp column with value in format  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

```
          spark.sql("""
            select current_timestamp(), now()  from dbo.products 
            """
      ).display()
```

Expected :

```
         2023-08-25 09:04:21.684  2023-08-25 09:04:21.684
```

Actual :

```
        2023-08-25T09:04:21.684+0000     2023-08-25T09:04:21.684+0000
```

Comment: When i try the same above query with display() method via notebook then i got that T and + symbol, if i apply show() dataframe method then it works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp, date_format, expr, concat
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSQLExample").getOrCreate()

result = spark.sql("""
    SELECT
        current_timestamp() as current_time
""")

result_with_format = result.withColumn(
    "current_time_formatted",
    concat(
        date_format(result["current_time"], "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"),
        expr("'+0000'")
    )
)

result_with_format = result_with_format.withColumn(
    "current_time_converted",
    result_with_format["current_time_formatted"].cast(TimestampType())
)

result_with_format.show(truncate=False)
```

I got same format as you are getting so use this transformation for your desired output

[image]

The default behavior of show and display in Databricks might indeed be showing different formats for timestamps due to their specific implementations and settings. In standard PySpark, the show function would typically display timestamps in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", while the display function in Databricks could be configured to show timestamps in the desired "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+0000" format.

If you are working within the Databricks environment, using display might already be set up to display timestamps in a more human-readable format. If you are observing different behaviors between show and display, it might be a feature specific to Databricks. To ensure consistency and desired formatting, you might want to refer to Databricks documentation or settings for timestamp display preferences.

for more info visit this
[a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67219012/databricks-timestamp-format-how-to-find-exact-format)!

Comment: I can understand  you are explicitly replicating the issue , but dataframe show() method gives me correct result , only the issue is with display() method via databricks notebbok

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be casting `timestamp` to `string` data type.

Check below.

[image]